# Calling method in parent from user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

For some business related reasons I made a wizard navigation user control. Pretty simple: Next/Previous/Finish buttons.

Each of the parent pages that use this nav user control have a SaveData function, which saves the data and does a bunch of other stuff.

When the user clicks Next/Previous/Finish I want to call the parent's SaveData function before redirecting to the other page. How should I do this or can you recommend a better way (code examples if possible please)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably best not to call it directly, that will make the user control non-portable. Instead, have an event on the control that the page can subscribe to. For example, your control has an `OnSave` event, so when you declare the control on your page you might do something like `<uc:MyControl runat="server" OnSave="SaveData" />`

Answer (score 5):

**UserControl** should not call **Parent**'s function. It is not a good design.

Instead, you want to bubble up the event from **UserControl** to the **Parent** page.

Note: my project's namespace is **DemoWebForm**.

### MyUserControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="DemoWebForm.MyUserControl" %>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="NextButton" 
    OnClick="NextButton_Click" Text="Next" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="PreviousButton" 
    OnClick="PreviousButtonn_Click" Text="Previous" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="FinishButton" 
    OnClick="FinishButton_Click" Text="Finish" />
```

### MyUserControl.ascx.cs

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event ClickEventHandler NextClicked;
    public event ClickEventHandler PreviousClicked;
    public event ClickEventHandler FinishClicked;

    protected void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NextClicked != null)
        {
            NextClicked(sender, e);
        }
    }

    protected void PreviousButtonn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousClicked != null)
        {
            PreviousClicked(sender, e);
        }
    }

    protected void FinishButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinishClicked != null)
        {
            FinishClicked(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Parent.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Parent.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="DemoWebForm.Parent" %>

<%@ Register Src="MyUserControl.ascx" TagName="MyUserControl" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <uc1:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControl1" runat="server"
            OnNextClicked="MyUserControl1_NextClicked"
            OnPreviousClicked="MyUserControl1_PreviousClicked"
            OnFinishClicked="MyUserControl1_FinishClicked" />
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="MessageLiteral" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Parent.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Parent : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void MyUserControl1_NextClicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLiteral.Text = "Next button was clicked";
    }

    protected void MyUserControl1_PreviousClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLiteral.Text = "Previous button was clicked";
    }

    protected void MyUserControl1_FinishClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageLiteral.Text = "Finish button was clicked";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Great example! But the question was tagged in VB.NET. If you know VB, perhaps you might switch it to use VB instead? I'd do it for you, but I can only read VB, I can't write it.

Comment: You can use [Telerik Convert Code](http://converter.telerik.com/). Sorry, I haven't written VB for few years already.

Comment: In Parent.aspx should OnNextClicked be NextClicked? (same for the others)

Comment: I tried using your example and for the ClickEventHandler I receive "The type or namespace 'ClickEventHandler' could not be found are you missing a using directive...". What's the using directive for ClickEventHandler?

Comment: @DovMiller Could you please create a new question, and post a link here? I'll gladly take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

you only need the delegate:

```
public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event ClickEventHandler NextClicked;
```